# React Native - Xcode 12.1 & iOS 14.0.1 Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, ios14

Below are the errors while bundling iOS from Terminal -

Version - Xcode 12.1 & iOS 14.0.1

```
    Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
    [Mon Dec 07 2020 17:31:28.708]  LOG      BASE_URL https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx/
    [Mon Dec 07 2020 17:31:28.815]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
    [Mon Dec 07 2020 17:31:28.832]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
    [Mon Dec 07 2020 17:31:29.907]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```